# Usage of 'Include' in PHP

Tags: php

**Brief background about my question:**

I'm going to start a new project that will have various functionality. I need to organise functions based on modules. For example member related functions goes into member class in `member.php` and gallery related function goes into gallery class in `gallery.php`. And these files will be in folder `root/modules/`. There will be many files under this folder representing each modules.

I will use `htaccess` to redirect any requested to `index.php` and this file will do all that is necessary to display the page.

So based on above (*redirection and using single file to handle all request*) I'll be using PHP `include` function to include all modules.

I'm not sure if including all modules is going cause any problem.

**Need advice on:**

- Whether Including all modules is going to cause any problem related to
  speed etc
- Is there any recommendations / alternative to include modules

Comment: Only include the files you really need and wrap all code into objects - check this function: `spl_autoload_register()`. I can also suggest to make a folder for each module (like in Zend Framework), because you might be going to place more than 1 file per "module": `root/modules/Gallery/...`

Comment: I would suggest, that you write one php for each file, and that `index.php` just redirects to the correct one. So you only need to load the modules you really need (within the specialised php's)

Comment: I suggest you go ahead and look into a modular based framework for this, why re-invent the wheel when you clearly have no idea what you are doing. Sorry for harsh criticism.

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 What if I'm trying to build a simple framework sick of bulky others? So I obviously have to go find a better wheel

Comment: @Lepanto Well a good framework will only load what you require it to, despite having a large footprint, they will be worked hard to be optimised for memory and performance, I can't see your "wheel" being better if your asking this kind of question to be honest mate.

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 I would take your suggestion into consideration that `we have to load only what is required` while building my wheel

Answer (score 1):

## Using the SPL-Autoloader

There is the [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://www.php.net//manual/de/function.spl-autoload-register.php) functions which allows you to specify a custom autoloading function. As of PHP 5.3.0 you can even specify a closure.

The cool thing about using an autoloader is, that it will load the requested files on demand, so you will have no overhead including all files on your request.

That means instead of throwing an error when a class could not be instantiated because it was not found, it will fire your autoload function and pass the requested class. Then your autoloader needs to load the proper file of course.

**Sample**

*/autoloadsample.php*

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function($class){

    include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';

});

$user = new User();

$user->test();
```

*/classes/User.php*

```
<?php

class User {

    public function test()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
    }

}
```

As you can see we did not include the */classes/User.php* file manually. Still everything will work here.

## Using Composer

Altough the SPL-Autoloader will work for small sized projects it's not necessarily the best solution. If you have a complex project structure you would need to care yourself about where the files you want to load are located all over your project.

Fortunately we got [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). It's a neat PHP Package/Dependency manager that also provides you with an autoloader.

Once you've installed composer it's pretty easy to bootstrap the autoloading.

Create a `composer.json` in your projects root.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "ProjectDomain"
        ]
    }
}
```

It's just a plain old json file. The classmap array takes strings of directories that you want to be autoloaded.

Then use the command line to switch to the projects working directory and

`composer install` or `composer.phar install` (if you have not installed composer globally)

Composer will create a `vendor/` directory for you that normally contains the dependencies you've required from within your `composer.json` but since we don't need any we will just skip that.

In that directory you will find an `autoload.php` file which you can now just request from your Front-Controller.

*index.php*

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$user = new User();

$user->test();
```

Composer also supports [PSR-*X*](http://www.php-fig.org/) autoloading. So that you can use namespaced classes and composer will handle all the autoloading. That could for example look like this.

*composer.json*

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Project\\": "ProjectDomain"
        }
    }
}
```

*ProjectDomain/User.php*

```
<?php namespace Project;

class User {

    public function test()
    {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }

}
```

*index.php*

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$user = new Project\User();

$user->test();
```

Make sure to run `composer dump-autoload` whenever you make autoloading-related changes to your composer.json file.